# How Can i Restrict My Search from based on Details (Description)

Tags: magento-1.9, search

I need to restrict name search based on details (details). I want name search applicable only on products name, how can i restrict name search based on details(description)

Answer (score 0):

Use a module, either custom or one already available. The default Magento search function doesn't really provide advanced features and customization.

I suggest something on the marketplace or [PureClarity](http://www.pureclarity.com)